# regex to filter results sqlite

Tags: regex, database, sqlite

I have data in sql lite table called file_path like following

```
full_path
---------
H:\new.docx
H:\outer
H:\outer\inner1
H:\outer\inner2
H:\outer\inner1\inner12
H:\new.docx
H:\outer\in1.pdf
H:\outer\inner1\in11.jpg
H:\outer\inner1\inner12\in121.wma
H:\new1.doc
H:\new2.rtf
H:\new.txt
```

I want to get the rows which are direct child of "H" means I do not want files/folders which are inside a folder. Is it possible using regex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd look for rows that start with `h:`, but contain only one `\` character (no subfolders).

So:

```
select * from file_path where 
 (full_path like 'h:%') and 
 not (full_path like '%\%\%');
```

Comment: This was really simple and stupid solution...great work mate.. Thanks

Comment: hey Paul, This slashes are creating issues... Can you guide me to resolve it... Is there any way to force string comparision without escape chars.